# Issue with org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce imports in Apache Hadoop 2.2

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I recently installed the new Hadoop 2.2. I had previously written a simple Word Count MapReduce program which used to work with ease on CDH4. But now, I have problems with all `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` imports. Can someone tell me which jar exactly to export to fix these imports? The code is as follows just in case someone needs to point out changes I need to make to make sure it runs in Hadoop 2.2.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MapRWordCount {
    private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);
    private final static Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\w+");

    public static class WordCountMapper 
            extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final Text word = new Text();

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String valueString = value.toString();
            Matcher matcher = WORD.matcher(valueString);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                word.set(matcher.group().toLowerCase());
                context.write(word, ONE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer 
            extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final IntWritable totalCount = new IntWritable();

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            totalCount.set(sum);
            context.write(key, totalCount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MapRWordCount <input_path> <output_path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MapRWordCount.class);
        job.setJobName("MapReduce Word Count");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Define 'problems with imports'?

Comment: Well I am unable to find the right JAR file with the classes, for example for the `Mapper` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the JARs in the following locations:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

In maven, I had to add the following to the pom.xml and then build cleanly to be able to find the Mapper and Reducer classes in Java:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the following don't throw errors:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the location of appropriate JARs in Hadoop 2.2, then look under `share/hadoop/{common,hdfs,mapreduce}`. You will find files ending in `-2.2.0.jar` that are likely what you are looking for.

This should be the same as in CDH4, unless you installed the "MR1" version, which matches the Hadoop 1.x structure.

Answer (score -1):

Use this link to find whatever JAR's file you need

Download them , Right click on your Project
Go to Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add External JAR's

Comment: What link , cant see any?