# What are the jar files needed for sqoop to import cloud SQL tables as parquet file into GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, sqoop, google-cloud-sql, parquet

I'm trying to import CloudSQL tables into GCS bucket using SQOOP.
I've used the below jars..

kite-data-core-1.1.0.jar,
kite-data-hive-1.1.0.jar,
kite-data-mapreduce-1.1.0.jar,
kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.1.0.jar.

below is my code snippet:

````
    ```sqoop import 
    -libjars=gs://BUCKET_NAME/kite-data-core-1.1.0.jar,gs://BUCKET_NAME/kite-data-mapreduce-1.1.0.jar,gs://BUCKET_NAME/kite-data-hive-1.1.0.jar,gs://BUCKET_NAME/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.1.0.jar,gs://BUCKET_NAME/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.2.0.jar 
    --connect=jdbc:mysql://IP/DB Name
     --username=sqoop_user 
    --password=sqoop_user 
    --target-dir=gs://BUCKET_NAME/mysql_output 
    --table persons 
    --split-by personid -m 2 
    --as-parquetfile```
````

I'm getting the below error...

> 20/01/03 04:42:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is
>   deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/DatasetKeyOutputFormat
>               at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob.getOutputFormatClass(DataDrivenImportJob.java:190)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.configureOutputFormat(ImportJobBase.java:94)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:259)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>               at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyOutputFormat
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)

In the first line of error, it says ' **mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar**'...

I've imported mapreduce.job.jar and passed it as libjar argument, but the issue still remains the same.

Help in this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: This link might help. https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-data-with-apache-sqoop-in-google-cloud-dataproc-4056b8fa2600

Comment: You can see [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) that mapred.jar is deprecated so instead of it, you've to import mapreduce.job.jar.

Comment: Can you share how are you importing the mapreduce.job.jar?

Comment: You can follow this [Apache Hadoop Official Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) and import all the necessary jars

Comment: And in Stackoverflow, there is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436361/issue-with-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-imports-in-apache-hadoop-2-2) which can help you.

Comment: I've dowloaded the latest version of mapreduce.job.jar from this link - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/3.2.1
As i'm working with GCP, i'm uploading the jar into GCS Bucket and passing it as 'libjar' argument.

Comment: I think mapreduce.job.jar is only an INFO message as it's saying in the first line, I think there are other errors like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ...                 
[Here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Sqoop-import-exception-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org/td-p/50758) you can find a solution to your issue.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405072/sqoop-integration-with-hadoop-throw-classnotfoundexception) will help you to solve your issue. Mapred.jar is deprecated was not an error if not an INFO message, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is the error in your case.

Comment: If the previous posts don't help you, please raise an issue in [Github](https://github.com/apache/sqoop)

Answer (score 0):

These are the specific jar versions that worked for me (mostly Cloudera):

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/parquet/parquet-format/2.9.0/parquet-format-2.9.0.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/sqoop/sqoop/1.4.7.7.2.10.0-148/sqoop-1.4.7.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/kitesdk/kite-data-core/1.0.0-cdh6.3.4/kite-data-core-1.0.0-cdh6.3.4.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/kitesdk/kite-data-mapreduce/1.0.0-cdh6.3.4/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0-cdh6.3.4.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/kitesdk/kite-hadoop-compatibility/1.0.0-cdh6.3.4/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0-cdh6.3.4.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/avro/avro/1.8.2.7.2.10.0-148/avro-1.8.2.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.8.2.7.2.10.0-148/avro-mapred-1.8.2.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-avro/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-avro-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-common/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-common-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-column/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-column-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-hadoop-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-jackson/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-jackson-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar
- https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/parquet/parquet-encoding/1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148/parquet-encoding-1.10.99.7.2.10.0-148.jar

Full script for the Sqoop job shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228090/47551).